# Tokenizing texts from Gutenberg archive for analysis

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x, http, natural-language-processing

I am writing a program to analyze books from the Gutenberg archive. The program takes the title and URL and finds the text and downloads it. Then it goes through the text and tokenizes it. Here is the code:

```
from urllib import request
import nltk
import os.path

canon_titles = [
    'Moby Dick',
    'Great Expectations'
]
canon_urls = [
    'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-0.txt',  # Moby Dick
    'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1400/1400-0.txt'
]
# Canon_beginnings is the location of where the book actually begins in
# the text file (skips headers, publisher info, etc.)
canon_beginnings = [
    28876,
    886
]
# canon endings exists just to grab a small amount of text for prototyping
canon_endings = [x + 500 for x in canon_beginnings]
canon_raw = [None] * len(canon_titles)
canon_tokens = [None] * len(canon_titles)
canon_words = [None] * len(canon_titles)
canon_words2tokens = [None] * len(canon_titles)
canon_pos = [None] * len(canon_titles)

# Now I combine all these together into a dictionary
canon_dict = {z[0]: list(z[1:]) for z in zip(canon_titles, canon_urls, canon_beginnings, canon_endings, canon_raw, canon_tokens,
                                             canon_words, canon_words2tokens, canon_pos)}

# Now I go through each title in the dict and see if I already have the text (I rerun this in Jupyter Notebook sometimes)
# And if not I grab it from online
for x in canon_dict:
    print("Working on {}".format(x))
    if canon_dict[x][3] == None:
        print("{} does not already exist, grabbing the text".format(x))
        url = canon_dict[x][0]
        response = request.urlopen(url)
        canon_text_draft = response.read().decode('utf8')
        canon_dict[x][3] = canon_text_draft[canon_dict[x][1]:canon_dict[x][2]]
    else:
        print("Already have this text, skipping")

# OK, now we'll tokenize, do parts of speech, etc.
def tokinze_text(raw_text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw_text)
    return tokens

# Now let's find the tokens
for x in canon_dict:
    print(canon_dict[x][3])
    canon_dict[x][4] = tokinze_text(canon_dict[x][3])
```

I would like to go much further with this - extracting parts of speech, rare words, etc., but I'm worried that my basic data structures are wrong. The python dictionary is feeling unwieldy as it gets larger. Should this entire thing be done in a pandas dataframe instead? Also, should the raw text be held in a separate structure from the rest? If I want to run a bunch of analysis on some of the results (like the tokenized text), will having the massive raw text slow everything down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the ideal place for a class. Each book is its own object with its own method of returning its tokens. I would make a method `tokens`, which I would make a property that fills itself on the first call to it.

Something like this:

```
from urllib import request
import nltk


class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title, url, start=0, end=-1):
        self.title = title
        self.url = url
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self._raw = None
        self._tokens = None
        # self.words = None
        # self.words2tokens = None
        # self.pos = None

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def raw(self):
        if self._raw is None:
            response = request.urlopen(self.url)
            draft = response.read().decode('utf8')
            self._raw = draft[self.start:self.end]
        return self._raw

    @property
    def tokens(self):
        if self._tokens is None:
            self._tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(self.raw)
        return self._tokens


if __name__ == "__main__":
    books = [Book('Moby Dick', 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-0.txt', 28876, 28876 + 500),
             Book('Great Expectations', 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1400/1400-0.txt', 886, 886 + 500)]

    for book in books:
        print book
        print book.tokens
```

I commented out the `words`, `words2tokens` and `pos` attributes as they are not currently needed.

Alternatively, if you don't want to insist on the delayed getting of the values, you can do it all already in the constructor:

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title, url, start=0, end=-1):
        self.title = title
        self.url = url
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.raw = self.get_raw(url)
        self.tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(self.raw)
        # self.words = None
        # self.words2tokens = None
        # self.pos = None

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_raw(self, url):
        response = request.urlopen(url)
        draft = response.read().decode('utf8')
        return draft[self.start:self.end]
```

Which you can use exactly the same way.

Comment: I noticed that you put the underscore after the "private" variables instead of before. Usually, I've seen them before. Is there a reason for doing them after?

Comment: @jss367 Nope, before is more correct. Apparently I didn't know better three years ago.

Comment: @jss367 Although in Python 3.8 writing that lazy property is no longer manual, you just use [`functools.cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property)